# Django form not storing values on validation fail

Tags: python, django

I can't get Django to retain entered form values when validation fails. I have created a test page and used the code in the Django guide, and it still doesn't work.

From the [Django guide](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/?from=olddocs#displaying-a-form-using-a-template%20Django%20guide):

> We call the form’s is_valid() method; if it’s not True, we go back to the template with the form. This time the form is no longer empty (unbound) so the HTML form will be populated with the data previously submitted, where it can be edited and corrected as required.

And here is my code:

```
#views.py

def test(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = NewAwardForm(request.POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            return redirect('/test/')

    else:
        form = NewAwardForm()

    print(form)
    return render(request, 'test.html', {'form': form})
```

---

```
test.html

<form action="/test/" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

---

```
forms.py

class NewAwardForm(forms.Form):
    recipient_email = forms.EmailField(label='Recipient Email', max_length=100)
```

---

Can anyone spot my mistake?

Comment: Double check the indentation in your actual code. The code you have posted here looks OK - when it's a POST request and the form is invalid, the view should render the template with the invalid form. Sometimes people put `form = NewAwardForm()` in the `else:` block ffor `if form.is_valid()`. This replaces the bound form with a new unbound form, so the errors are lost.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I double and triple checked the indentation, it's fine. I checked the terminal output as well from the print statement above the "return render" line, and the "form" var never changes.. It does not include the data I submitted in the form.

Comment: How are you actually entering invalid data? When I test your code in my browser, the html validation won't actually let me submit the form so the server doesn't receive the invalid data. When I altered the form to make it raise a `ValidationError` manually, your view/template display the error as expected.

Comment: Embarrassing error... I just realized what was going on as you replied. Thanks a million for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django renders the email field with `type="email"`. The HTML validation will prevent the browser from submitting an invalid email to the server.

You could test the view by adding a clean method to the form that rejects any emails ending in "example.com".

```
class NewAwardForm(forms.Form):
    recipient_email = forms.EmailField(label='Recipient Email', max_length=100)

    def clean_recipient_email(self):
        if self.cleaned_data['recipient_email'].endswith('example.com'):
            raise forms.ValidationError("No example.org emails allowed")
```

Now, if you enter `hello@example.com` and submit the form the HTML validation will allow the request to be submitted, the `clean_recipient_email` method will raise a validation error, and you'll see that your view and template display the invalid form as expected.